# How to handle react state and pros update appropriately with reducer

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, state

I am new in react and I have been trying to make a setting page with reactjs. What I am trying to achieve is, when user loads page for the first time I want the setting page attributes to be loaded from react component state as there wont be any setting available, When users submits the data and the page is rendered second time those setting attributes should now be loaded from props that comes from redux-saga.
I have written code as under

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class Setting extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                settings_1: {},
                settings_2: {
                    child_one: {
                        subchild_one:true,
                        subchild_two:true
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.activateAuthLayout();
            if (this.props.user !== null && this.props.user.shop_id) {
                this.props.loadSettings({
                    payload: { ...this.props.user},
                });
            }

        }

        handleChange = (event) => {
            let data = {[event.target.name]: value= [event.target.value]};
            let newState = { ...this.state.settings_2.child_one, data };
            this.setState({settings_2: newState });
        }


        render() {

            if(!this.props.is_settings_loaded){
                return (
                    <div>loading...</div>
                )
            }

            return (
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-0">
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            className="custom-control-input"
                            id="checkbox1"
                            name="subchild_one"
                            checked={this.props.settings.settings_2.child_one.subchild_one || this.state.settings_2.child_one.subchild_two}
                            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
                        />
                        <label className="custom-control-label font-weight-normal darktextcolor" htmlFor="sync_all_product_attributes">Select All</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            );
        }

    }

    const mapStatetoProps = state => {
        const { user } = state.Common;
        const { settings, is_settings_loaded } = state.Settings;
        return { user, settings, is_settings_loaded };
    }

    export default withRouter(connect(mapStatetoProps, { activateAuthLayout, loadSettings, updateSettings })(Setting));
```

Everything is working, except, when there is setting available on props and I want to unchecked the checkbox, it is never unchecked. I found that is because now i have props and that is not changed. How can I handle such scenario ?

I tried with defaultChecked instead of checked but I have select all checkbox, which will not work if I use defaultCheck.

Any kind of suggestion are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### about redux and react states

one first issue to address is you are mirroring your redux's state into react's state. This is an anti-pattern, you should follow single source of truth to avoid discrepancies.

---

**fix the state you consume**

In that retrospect, you should remove from your react's state the redux's state related. Then your `handleChange` should use `this.props.updateSettings` to update your redux's state. This way everything your data at your Component will be reflected correctly.

for your handleChange logic a checkbox you should use the property `checked`. Also it seems that you have some errors on data build and newState. You are wrapping your value into an array, and it seems you are assigning to `value` variable, which is not declared

you should pass the next redux's state to your `updateSettings`, something like:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    let data = {[event.target.name]: event.target.checked};
    let newState = { ...this.props.settings_2.child_one, ...data };
    this.props.updateSettings(newState);
}
```

also your input `name` should be `subchild_one` instead of `child_one`, and your checked should point to your props `subchild_one` only:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    className="custom-control-input"
    id="checkbox1"
    name="subchild_one"
    checked={this.props.settings_2.child_one.subchild_one}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.Sorry my bad, I made mistake while rebuilding my query. I have corrected as you have done in you answer. But if I simply put state value in the input, then the user saved data wont be reflected. If user has unchecked that input it should be unchecked and vise versa which wont be achieved from state only

Comment: @SuzAannshrestha I edited my answer given you are using redux. you should not mirror a redux's state into react's state, this is will lead you into trouble.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer. So I should not use local state of component, I need to use the state from redux instead right ?

Comment: yes, if you have a redux's state you should not copy that state into a react's state, you should consume directly from redux and use your defined actions to handle the state. you can still have any other react's state, but they should not be related to your redux's state.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it to me. :)